# Перенаправление с поддомена www на основной сайт. Ошибка SSL сертификата.

Tags: redirect, https, ssl

Здравствуйте!
Купил ssl сертификат на домен site.ru

Хочу назначить редирект c https://www.site.ru на https://site.ru, но не получается его сделать из-за ошибки сертификата.

Существует ли способ реализовать его без покупки сертификата на поддомены?

Comment: плохой серт, обычно www и пара других поддоменов включены в обычный сертификат.

Comment: @eicto Thawte SSL123

Comment: Вроде покупка на `www.site.com` даёт возможность использовать его и на `site.com`, но не наоборот.

Comment: @TheDoctor там засада, если ваш продавец сертификата не делает автомтом CN для www.example.com и example.com, то вполне может оказаться, что вы заказали сертификат только на www :! одноуровневые вилдкардные тоже не очень дорого сейчас стоят.

Comment: Всем, спасибо, все верно. Вот, что ответили в поддержке. Так как домен заказан только для домена site.ru, реализовать его для домена www.site.ru невозможно. Соответственно,установить переадресацию с https://www.site.ru на https://site.ru невозможно. Будьте внимательны при покупке сертификатов!

Answer (score 1):

Некоторые сертификаты некоторых CA умеют работать на доменах с www и без www, то есть для защиты `www.domain.ru` и `domain.ru` достаточно одного сертификата, но заказывать его нужно на `www.domain.ru`. Сертификат, заказанный на `domain.ru` покроет только `domain.ru` и не покроет `www.domain.ru`.

Написаное актуально для сертификатов, в том числе:

- RapidSSL
- QuickSSL Premium
- True BusinessID
- True BusinessID with EV

Как обстоят дела с поддержкой поддомена `www.*` у именно вашего CA, необходимо уточнять перед покупкой.

Так как Вы уже купили сертификат для `domain.ru`, единственным выходом для правильной работы HTTPS-редиректа с `www.domain.ru` будет перевыпуск сертификата на `www.domain.ru` сейчас или в будущем.